# VBS bot not working properly

Tags: vbscript, bots, notepad

Currently I'm making a bot which ultimately should simply play a song on a website, but the bot simply is unable to click the button. I aquired the name of the button by inspecting the HTML code on the website. I will show my code below and also add a picture which shows what might be wrong with my code:

```
set webbrowser = createobject("internetexplorer.application")
webbrowser.statusbar = false
webbrowser.toolbar = false
webbrowser.menubar = false
webbrowser.visible = true

webbrowser.navigate("https://skiomusic.com/gravit/noah-kahan-hurt-somebody-gravi-t-remix")

WScript.sleep(8000)

webbrowser.document.all.item("div.playBtn").click

WScript.sleep(10000)

webbrowser.Quit
```

[Line 11, character: 1, error: object required, source: microsoft runtime error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPPm1.png)

My question is obviously, how do I fix this error?

Comment: What is `div.playBtn` supposed to be? A `<div>` tag with the CSS class `playBtn`? That can't be selected like that. You need to select the `<div>` elements and check their `class` attribute. You may also try `getElementsByClassName()`, but in my experience that usually fails. I'm not quite sure under which circumstances it works and which prevent it from working.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I'm going to be honest, I don't quite understand your comment, but if you'd like to help me out; the site of which I'm trying to click the play button with my code is the following: https://skiomusic.com/gravit/noah-kahan-hurt-somebody-gravi-t-remix

Answer (score 0):

Well.. it seems you did not inspect the HTML code well enough. `div.playBtn` means nothing. I've looked at the page and saw the button does not have an id, but it does have a class by name of `playBtn`. In order to find this object, you should use the `getElementsByClassName` function wich returns a collection. From that collection you want the first item.

Try this

```
Option Explicit

Dim webbrowser, button
Set webbrowser = createobject("internetexplorer.application")
webbrowser.statusbar = False
webbrowser.toolbar   = False
webbrowser.menubar   = False
webbrowser.visible   = True

webbrowser.navigate("https://skiomusic.com/gravit/noah-kahan-hurt-somebody-gravi-t-remix")

WScript.sleep(8000)  ' why wait so long??

Set button = webbrowser.Document.getElementsByClassName("playBtn").Item(0)
button.Click

WScript.sleep(10000)

webbrowser.Quit
```

Comment: come to think of it... It may be better to use `Do While webbrowser.Busy Or webbrowser.ReadyState <> 4: WScript.Sleep 100: Loop` instead of `WScript.sleep(8000)`. Just a thought..